# aiotthp mysql server has gone away

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, aiohttp

When I run an aiohttp basic server for sometimes and keeps it idle, I m getting the error MySQL server has gone away,

I have the db connection as follows

```
async def init_db(app):
    conf = app["config"]["mysql"]

    engine = create_engine(
        f"mysql+mysqlconnector://{conf['user']}:{conf['password']}@{conf['host']}:"
        f"{conf['port']}/{conf['database']}", pool_pre_ping=True, pool_recycle=3600
    )

    app["db_session"] = sessionmaker(bind=engine)

def create_app():
    app = web.Application()
    app["config"] = config

    add_routes(app)

    app.on_startup.append(init_db)
    return app
```

Increasing pool size of mysql didnt work  and Im using sqlalchemy
Is this something to do with asynchronous nature ? or is there a workaround for this?

Comment: Can you provide sample code where your exception is generated? This is all standard setup code. Note also that by itself SQLAlchemy is blocking and not suitable for use with asyncio.

Comment: The `sqlalchemy_aio` package might be a suitable solution see https://sqlalchemy-aio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: @Tim the error happens when trying to establish a connection mainly from the database connection code